# Replace error list instead of append Json

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax

HI i have the bleow json code to validate a form when data is enetred wrong, if the data is enetered wrong more than once when create button is clicked it appends all the data again and still has the first set of errors, is there a way to remove the current errors and replace them with updated ones when the button is clicked?

```
        function CreateChild() {
        $("#formErrors").remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: rootURL,
            dataType: "json",
            data: formToJSONCreate(),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('Child Added Succesfully');
                clearCreateForm();
                displayList();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var errors = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText).ModelState
                var errorText = Object.keys(errors).map((key) => errors[key])
                console.log(Object.keys(errorText))

                $('#formErrors').append(errorText.join(' <br>'))

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: yes, use .html() instead of .append(). RTM - http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: that done it, wont let me select this as the right answer

Comment: That's because I wrote it as a comment. I've now added as a full answer which you can accept - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, simply use `.html()` instead of `.append()`

```
$('#formErrors').html(errorText.join(' <br>'));
```

See http://api.jquery.com/html/ for details of this method.